# Can you group together multiple SQL count statements?

Tags: sql

I have a database table that records transactions in a shop. The main data recorded is the cost of each item. E.g.

---

```
Item       || Cost
TV         || 80.00
XboxGame   || 55.00
Monitor    || 45.00 
Controller || 15.00
```

---

I want to find out the number of items purchased that cost less than $25, how many cost between $25 and $49.99, and how many cost $50 and above. This should be the result of running the sql command:

---

Table1 (Target):

```
Cost           || Number of Items
==================================
Less than $25  || 1
$25 - $49.99   || 1
$50 and above  || 2
```

---

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
        FROM tblTransactions
        WHERE (Cost < 25)) AS [Less than $25],

        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
        FROM tblTransactions AS tblTransactions_1
        WHERE (Cost >= 25) AND (Cost < 50)) AS [$25 - $49.99],

        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
        FROM tblTransactions AS tblTransactolions_2
        WHERE (ContributionAmount >= 50)) AS [$50 and above];
```

However this produces:

---

Table 2 (actual result)

```
Less than $25 || $25 - $49.99 || $50 and above
========================================
1             ||   1           || 2
```

---

My main question is: how do I change my SQL so that it produces Table 1, instead of Table 2?

Comment: *Which* SQL engine is being used?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Group By`:

```
Select 
  [Cost] = CASE WHEN cost < 25 then 'Less than $25' 
  WHEN cost >= 25 and cost < 50 then '$25 - $49.99'
  WHEN cost >= 50 then '$50 and above' END
,COUNT(*) As [Count]
FROM tblTransactions
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN cost < 25 then 'Less than $25' 
  WHEN cost >= 25 and cost < 50 then '$25 - $49.99'
  WHEN cost >= 50 then '$50 and above' END)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN
  cost < 25 then '1' 
  WHEN cost >= 25 and cost < 50 then '2'
  WHEN cost >= 50 then '3' END
```

Edited to include a sorting.

Comment: Almost correct. The column values appear as '25-49.99' then '50 and above' then 'less than 25'. But I want less than 25 to be the first displayed

Comment: If I put that line after the code it complains that column Cost is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or group by function.

Comment: Sorry, that ORDER BY was incorrect and I removed it. :)

Comment: @JohnTownsend - Please see if that works as desired. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have separate queries that are unioned together:

```
SELECT 'Less than $25' AS [Cost], COUNT(*) AS [Number of Items]
FROM tblTransactions
WHERE (Cost < 25)

UNION ALL

SELECT '$25 - $49.99', COUNT(*)
FROM tblTransactions AS tblTransactions_1
WHERE (Cost >= 25) AND (Cost < 50)

UNION ALL

SELECT '$50 and above', COUNT(*)
FROM Transactions AS tblCoachBudgetHistory_2
WHERE (ContributionAmount >= 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'Some text' AS [Label],
   COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE SomeCol = 'some val'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Some text' AS [Label],
   COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE SomeCol = 'some val'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a UNION

```
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count,
          , "Less than $25" AS Label
       FROM tblTransactions
      WHERE Cost < 25)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
          , "$25 - $49.99" as Label
       FROM tblTransactions
      WHERE (Cost >= 25) AND (Cost < 50))
UNION ALL
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
           ,"$50 and above" as Label
       FROM Transactions
      WHERE ContributionAmount >= 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing this, I would start with a subquery (or view) to first *group* the values into buckets.

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN (Cost >= 50) THEN 50
          WHEN (Cost >= 25) THEN 25
          ELSE 0 END) as costLevel
FROM transactions t
```

Then it's trivial to group.

```
SELECT
    (CASE costLevel WHEN 50 THEN '$50 and above'
                    WHEN 25 THEN '$25 - $49.99'
                    ELSE 'Less than $25' END) as [Cost]
  , COUNT(*) AS [Number of Items]
FROM (thePreviousQuery) AS cl
GROUP BY costLevel
-- optional:
-- ORDER BY costLevel
```

The above syntax is for SQL Server, so YMMV elsewhere. (I've also treated `tblTransactions` and `Transactions` as a typo.)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I tend to prefer range tables for this;

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM (VALUES ('Less than $25', CAST(0 as DECIMAL(5, 2)), CAST(25 as DECIMAL(5, 2))),
             ('$25 - $49.99', 25, 50),
             ('$50 and above', 50, null)) Range(name, lower, upper)
LEFT JOIN Transactions
       ON cost >= lower 
          AND (upper IS NULL OR cost < upper)
GROUP BY name
```

(and [working fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d70d92/3).  Should work on any RDBMS, pretty much)
This has the added benefit that the table can actually be persisted, meaning maintainable by end-users.  Also, an index on `cost` can be used by the optimizer, meaning potentially better performant queries.  Due to the `LEFT JOIN`, you'll also get a `0` count for ranges that have no transactions.